# I am confused about what colors should I use and how to use it?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I need to build a clock app like the "Samsung clock app" using jetpack compose.
I read [the Mapping accent roles](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles)

but when I want to start to build the design of my app I feel confused so
-I need some help.
-I need also to use dynamic colors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL3hn.png) / [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iqwA.png) / [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSekN.png) /

Comment: Did you check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#dynamic_color_schemes?

Comment: material 3 site give more inforamtion